# SQL Server - ensuring a complex relation on insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, referential-integrity

I have some related tables:

`Application` - stores a list of applications
`ApplicationInstall` - for each application, multiple installations are present (I have a foreign key `ApplicationUid`)
`SecurityPrincipal` - for each `ApplicationInstall` I have many principals (I have a foreign key `ApplicationInstallUid`).

I have also a table `SecurityPrincipalType`, linked to `Application` through a 1-to-many.

I would like to have a rule that guarantees that when I insert a record in `SecurityPrincipal` its Type comes from a `SecurityPrincipalType` linked to the correct `Application`.

I didn't rename the tables because I usually prefer to have names to think about. But I think the following scenario is equivalent:

`Table A` n..1 `Table B` 1..n `Table C`

And I want to enforce that a column in `C` contains only values coming from `A`, but linked via `B`.

I'm considering:

- triggers
- foreign keys?
- application level checks (but I would prefer to have some check at the db level)

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Foreign Key for this if you add a unique constraint on `Application(Id,SecurityPrinicpalType)`, something like this:

```
--drop table if exists ApplicationInstallSecurityPrinicpal
--drop table if exists ApplicationInstall
--drop table if exists Application

go

create table Application
(
  Id int identity not null, 
  SecurityPrincipalType int,
  constraint pk_Apppliction
    primary key (Id),
  constraint ak_Application
    unique(Id,SecurityPrincipalType)
)

create table ApplicationInstall
(
  ApplicationId int not null,
  Id int identity not null,
  constraint pk_ApplicationInstall
    primary key (ApplicationId,Id),
  constraint fk_ApplicationInstall_Application
    foreign key (ApplicationID) 
    references Application(Id)
)


create table ApplicationInstallSecurityPrinicpal
(
  ApplicationId int not null,
  ApplicationInstallId int not null,
  Id int identity not null, 
  SecurityPrincipalType int,
  constraint pk_ApplicationInstallSecurityPrinicpal
    primary key (ApplicationId,ApplicationInstallId,Id),
  constraint fk_ApplicationInstallSecurityPrinicpal_ApplictionInstall
    foreign key (ApplicationId,ApplicationInstallId)
    references Application(ApplicationId,Id)
  constraint fk_ApplicationInstallSecurityPrinicpal_Appliction
    foreign key (ApplicationId,SecurityPrincipalType)
    references Application(Id,SecurityPrincipalType)
)
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I need, but I don't have ApplicationId on the SecurityPrincipal table, and I have multiple PrincipalTypes is a table linked to Application, but I can use the same technique using composite foreign keys. Paying 8 bytes for each row should be acceptable. Many, many thanks for the pointer!